# Why does the first and second case keep returning false when both the original and reversed strings are the same? Palindrome code

Tags: c++

Why does the function return false for the first and second words when they are both palindromes? The reversed text should be the same as the original.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Define is_palindrome() here:
bool is_palindrome(std::string text) {
    std::string reversed = "";
    for (int i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.push_back(text[i]);
    }

    if (reversed == text) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
    int main() {
        std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
        std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
        std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";

    }
```

Comment: But when I print the words, they look the same?

Comment: When you do `reversed.push_back(text[i])` when `i == text.size()` what you do is add a null character.  That character does not print so they will look the same, but they are different.  With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `if(reversed==text) return true; else return false;` just do `return reversed == text;`

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful.

Comment: Note that you do not have to reverse the string to test for palindrome-ness. Compare the first and last characters and march inward until the characters you are comparing meet or cross in the middle. If you reach the middle without a false compare, you found a palindrome. This is much, much faster.

Comment: As @user4581301 suggested, something like this would be quicker: `return  std::equal(text.begin(), 
                                std::next(text.begin(), text.size() / 2),
                                text.rbegin());`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't want to do the work, but since you did it (and it took less text than my explanation) you might as well drop that as an answer. Never mind. Scooped by Vlad.

Comment: @user4581301 I would have mentioned it as a sidenote if I'd written an answer to OP:s question, but there are already two good answers so ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
for (int i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.push_back(text[i]);
    }
```

Notice that you are indexing from `.size()`, but that is not correct. The character at position `text[text.size()]` is guaranteed to be `\0`. This is probably not part of the string whose 'palindrome-ness' you want to check.

You need to do

```
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.push_back(text[i]);
    }
```

If you actually want to reverse a string, you could just use `std::reverse` like this

```
auto rev = text;
std::reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
```

and then compare with `rev == text`.

Note that if you just want to check if a string is a palindrome, there are much more efficient ways to do it. To start off, your example is making 2 unnecessary copies; one in the function parameter, and one to store the reversed string.

Change the signature to take by const reference, and use an algorithm

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string const &text) 
{
  return std::equal(text.begin(), 
                    text.begin() + text.size() / 2, 
                    text.rbegin());
}
```

Comment: But when I print the word, it looks the same as the original.

Comment: Starting with C++11, that index at the end is ok; it returns `\0`. So the reversed string would be valid, but different from the original.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks a lot. I didn't know that. Edited answer.

Comment: @Mussie *But when I print the word* -- This is not a valid test.  What if there are unprintable characters in the string, and you just won't see them?  This is where you need to use a debugger, or at the very least, *programmatically* verify that the strings are the same.

Comment: @cigien It is a very bad behavior to copy and paste from my answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hey, I hope you're not serious. I only wrote this, since OP accepted my answer, and I thought it best to expand it a bit.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's not even the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your array bounding is incorrect. In C++ indices begin at 0 so the highest index of your array will be `text.size() - 1` Try this instead:

```
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.push_back(text[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function parameter should be constant referenced type

```
bool is_palindrome( const std::string &text ) {
```

In this loop

```
for (int i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed.push_back(text[i]);
}
```

when `i` is initially equal to `text.size()` when you are accessing a non-actual element of the string. According to the C++ 11 Standard it is equal to '\0'.

Also it is a bad idea to use the signed type `int` as the type of the index instead of the unsigned type `std::string::size_type`.

Moreover there is no need to create a copy of the whole string to determine whether the given string is a palindrome. This is just a bad approach because it is inefficient.

The function can be defined the following way

```
bool is_palindrome( const std::string &s ) 
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0, n = s.size();

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n - i - 1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome( const std::string &s ) 
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0, n = s.size();

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n - i - 1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
true
true
false
```

Another approach is to use the standard algorithm `std::equal`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_palindrome( const std::string &s ) 
{
    return std::equal( std::begin( s ), std::next( std::begin( s ), s.size() / 2 ),
                       std::rbegin( s ) );
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
true
true
false
```

If your compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard then it is even better to declare the function parameter as having the type `std::string_view`.

For example (or you can use the implementation with the standard algorithm `std::equal`)

```
#include <string_view>

bool is_palindrome( std::string_view s )
{    
    std::string_view::size_type i = 0, n = s.size();

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n - i - 1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

In this case you will be able to call the function selecting a sub-string of a string without creating an object of the type `std::string` as for example

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( { "adam", 3 } ) << "\n";
```

Comment: I have learned a lot just from this single answer. Thank you!